# Frontend cannot reach backend port in separate docker containers

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, containers, nestjs

My frontend app is behind NGINX, which serve static frontend files (written in Angular) in docker container, communication port is 80:80.

My backend app is NestJS, which serves data on port localhost:3000 in another docker container.

Starting app with docker-compose up, but my frontend cannot reach backend - getting 502, bad GW.

Is the issue caused by setup of nginx or docker-compose.yml or both?

Dockerfile frontend:

```
FROM node:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ARG configuration=production
RUN npm install && npm run build.prod

FROM nginx:latest
LABEL version="1.0"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/frontend/ .
```

Dockerfile backend:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
ADD . /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

NGINX.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

        location ~ \.html$ {
          add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
          add_header Expires "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
          add_header Pragma no-cache;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  angular:
    image: "docker-frontend:v3"
    container_name: "frontend"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - restapi

  restapi:
    image: "docker-backend:v1"
    container_name: "backend"
    expose: 
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Can you show an http request with url in your angular app?

Comment: An other question, did you try to call your endpoint from an external software like postman?

Comment: Request is to localhost/api/books [GET], response is 502 bad gateway. I can reach localhost:3000/api/books from host machine (MacOS) without any problem. I think the problem is, that behind nginx I am going for localhost:3000 but it is not the same localhost as my host where is backend container running.

Comment: did you mean localhost:3000/api/books ? 

  please copy paste this:

  const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/books";
  
  const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) }; 

return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, httpOptions);

Comment: I will try it, but I don't want to specify port in my angular (frontend) services, there I just want to use relative path like /api/books and then on nginx redirect every request to /api/* to localhost:3000.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use localhost inside the container to connect to another container, to achieve that you can use the name of your container

so for example

```
http://localhost:3000/api/
```

would be

```
http://backend:3000/api/
```

Comment: Understand, but this I have to use in nginx conf file for proxy pass? Because I don't want to specify port inside my angular services.

Comment: Okay so I changed location to backend:3000 instead of localhost and it works.